# Buscar un elemento HTML dentro de una estructura

Tags: javascript, html

como puedo buscar un elemento con JavaScript dentro de una estructura HTML ejemplo aquí:

```
<div id="undidadMedidad_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" data-backdrop="static">
    <div id="undidadMedidad_modal_form">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <form id="form-send">

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

quiero obtener el id del formulario a partir de id **undidadMedidad_modal** que es el primer div.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const div = document.getElementById('undidadMedidad_modal');

const miFormulario = div.querySelector('form');

console.log(miFormulario.id)
```

```html
<div id="undidadMedidad_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" data-backdrop="static">
        <div id="undidadMedidad_modal_form">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <form id="form-send">
    
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Obtienes el id del `form`, si eliminas **.id** obtienes la etiqueta completa (`<form>...</form>`)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con [**`querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) quien se encarga de buscar el elemento con el selector que le pases como parámetro, en tu caso, buscamos al id, puedes hacerlo así:

```
document.querySelector('#undidadMedidad_modal #form-send');
```

Aquí busco el elemento con el id `#form-send` quien se encuentre dentro del elemento con el id `#undidadMedidad_modal`.

Ejemplo:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#undidadMedidad_modal #form-send');
console.log(form);
console.log("id: " + form.id);
```

```html
<div id="undidadMedidad_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" data-backdrop="static">
  <div id="undidadMedidad_modal_form">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <form id="form-send">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```